# how to do insert, update and delete entries in a table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, insert, updates, sql-delete

| id | name | Createdat | Updatedat | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 25-12-2023 01:11:15 |  | true |
| 2 | B | 24-12-2023 12:12:12 | 25-12-2023 14:14:14 | false |

I am having table like above. I am getting set of ids along with other details as a json in my input. I need to insert the ids if its not already there. Need to update the existing one. If my inputs doesnt have ids which is already present in table, then i need to delete it. How to achieve this in postgresql function

I am beginner in postgresql. I tried to delete and insert instead of update but that makes me to loose createdat data present in table

Comment: How would you decide which row to delete if you don‘t have an id?

Comment: It seems to me that truncating the table and then inserting all your input records will do the job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql) Additional examples can be found on the Postgres documentation about [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

Comment: Truncating will delete created date information in my id records.